# SQL query - get the max of all counts

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an airport database:

[Airpot Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGFP0.jpg)

and I need to display the pilot ID of the pilot who flew the most times, this is my query:

```
SELECT 
    t.PilotID, MAX(t.flights) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         PilotID, COUNT(*) AS flights  
     FROM 
         Flights 
     GROUP BY 
         PilotID) AS t
```

without the `t.pilotID`, it works and shows only the max flights - but with
the `t.pilotID` I get this error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression "PilotID" as part of an aggregate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to use `top 1` keyword after an descending order based on the count. Try below:

```
SELECT top 1 PilotID, COUNT(*) AS flights 
FROM Flights 
GROUP BY PilotID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
```

Comment: the first thing didn't work its the same as doing the inner select alone - it shows all the count(*) for all pilots. and I really dont know what is that second thing but ive copied and pasted it and its an error.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using? SqlServer? Oracle? MySql?

Comment: @stavbitanski can you please try the edited part as well?

Comment: im using access

Comment: OK, the edited part worked for access? please let me know

Comment: It worked. Thank you!. I thought about doing the top 1 trick but wasnt sure

Answer (score 0):

You need Group By, Order By Desc, Top 1 & label the Count(flightCode) aggregate function:

```
SELECT Top 1 Flights.PilotID, Count(Flights.FlightCode) AS TTFlights
FROM Flights
GROUP BY Flights.PilotID
ORDER BY Count(Flights.FlightCode) DESC;
```